# What game does this video from Twitter come from?

Tags: game-identification

Green Man Gaming posted a tweet about International Pirates Day with a short gif video showing 2 characters bumping their fists, and I was wondering what game it came from since the characters look interesting.

The tweet can be found at https://twitter.com/GreenManGaming/status/1042390390333235200, with the corresponding video at https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DndQhAHWwAAoDfh.mp4. Below is a still image I extracted from the video source.

[image]

I'm particularly interested in who the character on the left is.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Those are Fran (left) and Balthier (right), two playable characters from Final Fantasy XII. They're "sky pirates", which explains their relevance in the tweet.